# How to modify code under vendor/ directory

Tags: laravel-5

Checking generated html of my laravel 5.7 app in https://validator.w3.org I got errors  like :

```
Error: Bad value navigation for attribute role on element ul.
From line 353, column 21; to line 353, column 61
          <ul class="pagination" role="navigation">↩
```

Searching  for similar code in my application I found several files like
vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pagination/resources/views/bootstrap-4.blade.php with code

```
@if ($paginator->hasPages())
    <ul class="pagination" role="navigation">
```

as this file is under /vendor directory, if there is a way to fix it for my app ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can run `php artisan vendor:publish --tag=laravel-pagination`, it will create pagination view in `resources/views/vendor/pagination` folder. Then you can customize and use it by adding to the first argument of `links()` method.

**List view:**

```
<div class="content">
    @foreach($posts as $post)
        ..blahblah..
    @endforeach
</div>

{{ $posts->links('vendor.pagination.view_name') }}
```

More here:
https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/pagination#customizing-the-pagination-view